# AWS Lambda publish-layer-version, getting: Unknown options: --compatible-architectures, x86_64

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I'm trying to create an AWS Lambda Layer using the AWS CLI on Ubuntu, like this:

```
aws lambda publish-layer-version \
  --layer-name numpy --description "numpy Python 3.9"  \
  --zip-file fileb://./lambda/deps/numpy/python.zip \
  --compatible-runtimes python3.9 \
  --compatible-architectures "x86_64" --output text --query "LayerVersionArn"
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Unknown options: --compatible-architectures, x86_64
```

I tried all sorts of combinations to no avail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root cause was that I had AWS CLI version "aws-cli/2.2.2" installed on my machine...

As soon as I updated to the latest (version aws-cli/2.4.16), it worked.

I hope this helps someone in the future.